# Поиск текста

Tags: delphi-7

Добрый день.

Имеется два memo (memo1, memo2), в memo1 загружен eXe в hex виде (больше 10.000 строк), в memo2 записаны 5-10 строчек (02 23 53 23 35 13 3D 3A Y3 такого типа). Нужно произвести поиск каждой строчки из memo2 в memo1.

```
if Pos(memo1.Lines, memo2,Text)<>0 then
...
```

Так не получается. Как реализовать это?

```
if Pos(mmo2.Text,mmo1.Lines.Text)<>0 then
ShowMessage('ok');
```

Так ищет, только если ввести строку, которая точно есть, но если ниже вписать еще одно строку, то не ищет. Возможно ли реализовать такое, только строки (не одна строка) для поиска будут записаны в txt файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда и брать нужно по одной, в чём проблемма? Для поиска второй строки:

```
Pos(mmo2.Lines[1], mmo1.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i := 0 to mmo2.Lines.Count - 1 do
begin
  if Pos(mmo2.Lines[i], mmo1.Text) > 0 then
    ShowMessage('ok');
end;
```